# How to query two different fields with different query terms in same request. ElasticSearch 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-rails

new to ElasticSearch - start loving it. I am working on a Rails application (using elasticsearch-rails / elasticsearch-model).

I have two fields - both strings consisting of Tags.

*about_me & about_you*

- Now I was to query the about_you of another user with the current users about_me.
- At the same time, I wish to query the about_me of the other users with the about_you of the current user.

Does this make sense? Like two fields, two queries and each query is aimed at a particular field.

I just need a hint how this can be achieved in ES. For the sake of completeness, here is the part method I created in my rails model - it is incomplete:

```
def home_search(query_you, query_me)
  search_definition =
      {
          query: {
              multi_match: {
                  query: query_me,
                  fields: ['about_you']
              }
              ..... SOMETHINGs MISSING HERE ..... ?
          },
          suggest: {
              text: query,
              about_me: {
                  term: {
                      size: 1,
                      field: :about_me
                  }
              },
              about_you: {
                  term: {
                      size: 1,
                      field: :about_you
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  self.class.__elasticsearch__.search(search_definition)
end
```

Any help, link or donations are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood your question but I can suggest two options:
First Use a `bool query` of type `should` and `minimum_should_match=1`. In this case you can write two queries for you'r searches. and If you want to distinguish between results you can pass a `_name` parameter in each query. something like this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "minimum_should_match": 1,
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "query_me",
                  "fields": [
                     "about_you"
                  ],
                  "_name": "about_you"
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "query_you",
                  "fields": [
                     "about_me"
                  ],
                  "_name": "about_you"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

By providing `_name` you can see which queries are hitted in your search result.
The second approach could be a `_msearch` query which in which you can pass multiple queries to the endpoint and get the results back.
Here are some useful links:

[Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
[Named Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html)

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Yes I was reading up on bool queries last night. A lot of into to take in - but promised myself to master it this week! Thank you for your input - very helpful!